# For my C code to construct a binary search tree and print the tree on its side is not printing anything?

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I am trying to write a program to construct a binary search tree and print the tree on its side. Read the input from the user as a sequence of integers and output the tree indented based on depth and with one value on each line. However, my code is working but not printing anything on console?
I think something might be wrong with my insert function but I am not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *left, *right;
};  
typedef struct node node;   
node *insert(node *t, int a){ //insert values in tree
  node* tmp= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));;  
  if (t==NULL) {
      tmp->data = a;
      tmp->left = NULL;
      tmp->right = NULL;
      return(tmp);
    }
  else if (a < t->data)
      t->left = insert(t->left,a);
    else
      t->right = insert(t->right,a);    
  return(t);
}
void print( node *t, int depth) {
    int i;
    if (t == NULL) 
        return;         
    print(t->right, depth + 1); 
    for (i = 0; i < 4 * depth; ++i)
        printf(" ");            
    printf("%d\n", t->data);        
    print(t->left, depth + 1);
}   
int main() {
    node *root= NULL;
    int n,a,i;
    printf("Enter number of values "); //7
    scanf("%d", &n);    
    printf("\nEnter numbers "); //10 6 14 4 8 12 16
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        insert(&root, a);
    }   
    print(root, 0); 
    return 0;
}
```

```
Input: 10 6 14 4 8 12 16
Expected output:
        16
    14
        12
10
        8
    6
        4
```

Comment: A quick issue a i see that you don't assign anywhere the return pointer of `insert()`. So the `root` remain always empty. And don't forget to `free` the allocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `insert` is

```
node *insert(node *t, int a) // t is a pointer to node
```

But you are passing a pointer to pointer to node

```
insert(&root, a);
```

I think you want

```
root = insert(root, a);
```

Comment: Yes, it was very easy to detect compiling with warnings :) `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘insert’ from incompatible pointer type insert(&root, a); `, take a look to https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-wall.html and you will save a lot of time

Comment: Also, consider using a `destroy()` function `free()`ing the nodes at the very end.